# PyCharm takes painfully long time to launch Telegram Bot

Tags: pycharm, telegram

So i'm making telegram bots with Pycharm IDE on my Linux laptop. I have been doing it for quite a while, but on my main bulky PC. Now i switched to Linux Ubuntu laptop, and anytime i need to test my bot, I'm launching it through Pycharm, and proceed to wait for solid one and a half minutes for it to actually start working. Is there anything i can do to make it load quicker?

Comment: I am not opposed to switch IDE btw

Comment: This has nothing to do with Ubuntu.  This has to do with your bot and the Python side of things, PyCharm is simply an IDE.  You can always launch your stuff manually on the command line to see if it loads faster, but this isn't a PyCharm support channel.  you can try directly launching your bot on the command line with Python to see if it works, but if it doesn't and has the same symptoms then the issue is not Python or Ubuntu, just your bot's code taking a long time to initialize.

Comment: As a test, I tried the same script I used on my big machine. Difference in time is like a minute.